# No reconoce las credenciales options, callback node js

Tags: nodejs, express

estoy haciendo una peticion con una funcion callback pero en el options estoy enviando el usuario y contraseña pero no los reconoce la funcion:

```
 let usuario = "MMMSSS" + ":" + "Hji880n2Tpn/"    
 let user = "Basic " + usuario.toString("base64");

 let options = {
  url: url,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    'Authorization': user
  },
  body: body,
  json: true
};
```

¿Cual seria la forma correcta para enviar las credenciales?

Comment: Hola Luis. Faltaría saber como lo envías y como esperas recibirlo en express. Usas algún middleware para recibir el token? En express puedes consultar el header dentro de un middleware con esta linea `req.headers.authorization`

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo solo convertí antes las credenciales a base 64 para pasarla ya como string a la variable user. Con eso funciono....

Comment: podrías ayudarme con mi pregunta?, necesito una ayudita con esto, por favor.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/571166/como-pasarle-par%c3%a1metros-a-mi-funci%c3%b3n-callback