# Como pasarle parámetros a mi función callback

Tags: nodejs, express, routes

Hola a todos tengo un ligero problema con el acceder o pasarle parámetros a una función `callback` dentro de mi ruta, la función consiste en que tienes que comprobar los roles que le paso como parámetro, previamente comprueba que está logeado; En el token que genero previamente y que doy al usuario cuando se logea se encuentra el rol, en caso de que sea el rol que tengo dentro del token igual a uno de los que le paso por parámetro puedes pasar a hacer la siguiente función.

El código es el siguiente:

```
routes/aaff.js

const { authMiddleware } = require('../middlewares/auth');
const { checkUserLogedRol } = require ('../utils/handleRoles');

route.post('/',authMiddleware,checkUserLogedRol.bind({rol:["ADMIN","CONSULT"]}),validateCreateAAFF,);
```

Dentro de `handleRoles` tengo lo siguiente:

```
const checkUserLogedRol = (roles, req, res, next) => {
    
    console.log(roles);
    res.send("checkeo");
    
}

module.exports = { checkUserLogedRol };
```

¿Alguna idea al respecto?, ¿se sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo logré que funcionara de la siguiente manera:

```
route.post('/',authMiddleware,(req, res)=>{
    checkUserLogedRol({rol:["ADMIN","CONSULT"]},req,res)
},validateCreateAAFF);
```

Creo que no es la mejor forma, pero mientras funcione..., ya probaré a mejorarlo en otro momento.